# Physical Win98 hd to VM .vmdk

Tags: vmware-fusion, hard-drive, vmware-vmdk

I am pretty new to VMware fusion.

Case is: I have an old Win 98 machine, on which I have a program i need to run, to which I do not have the installation CDs. For that reason I need to make a .vmdk from the physical HD of the machine, which I would like to run in Fusion on my Imac.

The old Win 98 box has two HD, an I have now used Ghost 6.0 to make a .GHO-image of the C-drive, and put the file-set (4 2GB files) on the D-drive. My plan now is to try to convert the .GHO-image in to a .vmdk-file.

Is there a cook-bock recipie on how to do that?

I have searched the forum, but did not find any explicit way to do it.

Do I have to use another imaging tool to "Ghost" the C-drive? Would it help to disconnect the C-drive HD from the Win 98 box, and mount it as an USB-drive in the Imac?

Any suggestion on how to solve this matter is very welcom.

BRG

/Johan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[qemu for mac](http://www.kju-app.org/) can convert from raw image to vm.

Check this forum post: http://qemu-forum.ipi.fi/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=4508#p13682

It's for converting from vdi to vmdk, so you'll need only the second part - from raw to vmdk.

You can use dd to get a raw image out of the hdd - just connect it to your mac, and the use:

dd bs=512 if=/dev/rXX# of=/some_dir/foo.dmg

where rXX# is where this HDD is assigned.

Comment: Nice - I'm going to keep a note of that for the future.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use [VMware Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/faqs.html). It will convert the Ghost image directly to a Virtual Machine in your VMware target system (Workstation, Fusion, ESX, Server). It may have problems with the Windows 98 part, I've never tried to use Converter against a Windows 98 ghost image as a source so I can't confirm whether it will actualyl work or not, but it's definitely worth a shot. You need to get the standalone version of Converter, the Enterprise version requires vCenter (and a license) but the standalone version is free.